# Number of subsets of {1, 2, ..., 12} in which no two elements of the subset differ by 3.

Tags: combinatorics

Question:

> A subset of {1, 2, ..., 12} is called trivoidant if no two elements of the subset
> differ by 3. Enter the number of trivoidant subsets of {1, 2, ..., 12}

My solution:

Consider the set {$3,6,9,12$}, we can make the following subsets where no two elements differ by 3: {}, {$3$}, {$6$}, {$9$}, {$12$}, {$3,9$}, {$3, 12$}, {$6,12$}. Similarly, we can do the same with the sets {$1,4,7,10$} and {$2,5,8,11$} and we would get the same number of subsets where no two elements differ by 3. For each of those 3 sets we choose one of its trivoidant subsets and the union of the 3 subsets chosen will give us a trivoidant subset of {$1, 2,...,12$} and since for each set we can choose from 8 subsets the answer is $8^3 = 512$

In which other ways can we get to the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Choosing a triavoidant subset of $\{3,6,9,12\}$ is equivalent to choosing a subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with no adjacent elements. You can prove by induction that the number of subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with no adjacent elements is the $(n+2)^\text{nd}$ Fibonacci number. That gives a more general explanation of where the $8$ comes from. Otherwise, I think your proof is the most sensible way to do this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)